# Can I run vSphere Client and ESXi at the same machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

Can I run vSphere Client and ESXi at the same machine? ... And is that a good idea?

I want to install ESXi with multiple images (Windows, Linux, etc...) and seamlessly use and switch between them. 
Or is it better to do the regular thing and install VMware Workstation Pro?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  ESXi is a type I hypervisor, meaning it runs on the bare metal.  Since it's basically a self-contained operating system, no other OS can run on the same machine.  You'll need a second machine running Windows, which has the vSphere client that connects to ESXi.  Once you have that set up, you can indeed make several virtual machines running whatever OS you like, and "seamlessly use and switch between them" from the vSphere client.  Indeed, that is the very purpose of virtualization.

If you just have one machine (with an OS already on it), you should run a Type II hypervisor such as VMware Workstation or Virtualbox.

Comment: You certainly can run vSphere within a ESXi VM, which means ESXi and vSphere are running on the same machine.  Add in a zero client and VMWare View and you don’t see any additional hardware other than the ESXi host itself

Comment: That's true but it's not what he asked.  You cannot access VM's directly from the ESXi host.  Sure, you can run the vSphere client on a guest, but you need a second machine to access that guest from, either via RDP or some other remote protocol.

Comment: You can use a zero client and VMWare View and a VMWare Center VM to access the VMs.

Comment: Again, I'll grant that what you say is technically true.  However, I don't see how that is useful to the person who posed the question.